# Selecting map/odom frames for GPS/IMU

Tags: ros, navigation, coordinate-system, map-to-odom, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello forum,

I am working on a project where I need to combine LIDAR scans and camera images from a drone. An INS mounted on the drone provides GPS and IMU information. I read REP 105 and tf tutorials multiple times and explored ROS answers on these packages. I believe I understand the concepts but I have some doubts in terms of application.

Let's say I have a **camera_frame**, **lidar_frame** and **imu_frame**, all of which are attached to base_link.
I can infer the transforms from these frames to the **base_link** since I know their offsets from the base_link origin (robot geometrical center).

As per my understanding, I can avoid discrete jumps due to GPS by setting **world_frame = odom**.  Also, I set the **imu_frame = odom**.

Please verify this statement:
Since I know the transform between **imu_frame** and **base_link**, I also know the
**odom->base_link** (since **imu_frame = odom**).

1. Does this also means I know where my robot is in the world_frame (since world_frame= odom)?
2. How do I use the map frame (if at all)? If I am using the GPS, should I be using world_frame= map?

I know I might be wrong with my understanding of these concepts and their application. I'd really appreciate any input from the good folk here at ROS Answers to help me better understand these fundamental tf concepts. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234766/selecting-map/odom-frames-for-gps/imu/) by [Venkat Ganesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26837/venkat-ganesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2016-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> As per my understanding, I can avoid
> discrete jumps due to GPS by setting
> world_frame = odom. Also, I set the
> imu_frame = odom.

No. What the documentation is trying to get across is that data that is subject to discrete jumps, like GPS data, should not be fused into your state estimate if your world frame is set to *odom*. Changing the frame to *odom* won't fix the behavior of the GPS data. However, if you are only running a single EKF instance and your `world_frame` is the same as your `odom_frame`, then it won't hurt anything. You'll just have to deal with your position jumping around.

Also, do not make the `frame_id` of your IMU data "odom." Create a *base_link->imu* transform, and make the `frame_id` of your IMU data *imu*.

There are numerous ROS answers questions regarding the *map/odom/base_link* frames and the way they're handled by robot_localization:

http://answers.ros.org/question/222702/how-to-use-resulting-map-odom-frame-data-from-ekf-filter-of-robot_localization-package/

http://answers.ros.org/question/203989/map-frame-from-robot_localization/

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0